# Detect the length of a lambda expression using Roslyn

Tags: c#, lambda, code-analysis, roslyn

I'm wondering how could one possibly detect the length (number of lines) when analyzing code using the Roslyn compiler. At the moment, I'm developing a law which prohibited the use of lambdas longer than 10 lines.

Looking at the example below, how could I know that the simple lambda expression syntax has only one line ?

```
        // Data source. 
        int[] scores = { 90, 71, 82, 93, 75, 82 };

        // The call to Count forces iteration of the source 
        int highScoreCount = scores.Where(n => n > 80).Count();
```

**EDITS**
What I would like to know, is exactly know the difference in the number of lines we can see in the lambda expression in the first example and in the one just below :

```
   1: private IEnumerable<Book> BooksPublishedBetween1991and1997()
   2: {
   3:     return Books.FindAll(Book => {
   4:  
   5:         return Book.Published >= new DateTime(1991, 01, 01) &&
   6:         Book.Published <= new DateTime(1997, 12, 31);
   7:     
   8:     });
   9: } //Link to sample :  http://www.rvenables.com/2009/03/practical-introduction-to-lambda-expressions/
```

**UPDATE**

It has been pointing out in the comments that my question is too broad. I'm going to try to simply it as much as I can. I have done code analysis before using Roslyn to validate certain development usage users should have when developing client software. 
I have a general way to go through the nodes of the tree code (not sure if it's really called like that) by using a SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext object.
What I would like to know is when I'm looking for SimpleLambdaExpressionSyntax and ParenthesisedLambdaExpressionSyntax, is the way to look at the content of the lambda expression and know exactly on how many lines the code was written.

Comment: It's hard to give an answer to that without knowing how you're integrating Roslyn into your build process. You basically want to find syntax nodes of the right kind, and then find the file position for them... Have you done *any* Roslyn integration yet?

Comment: The problem with the lines of code is that one can always make a lambda expression compact by putting it on a single line, for instance `Book => {return Book.Published >= new DateTime(1991, 01, 01) && Book.Published <= new DateTime(1997, 12, 31);}`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have some such as disabling the use of methods from various class or specifying the use of certain overloads when they're available.
I'm adding the Roslyn compiler and business rules as a nugget package in all my solutions. 
What I'd like to do is go through SimpleLambdaExpressionSyntax and ParenthesisedLambdaExpressionSyntax and make sure that the expressions are not longer than ten lines.

Comment: Right, so you know how to *get* the syntax node already? (That's the problem with this question - it's not specific about which part of the solution you need.)

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes, this is troublesome, but for now I'm just going to create my analysis rule to simply verifies each new lines and verify that it's not longer that ten lines. When that works, I'll try to find some way to manage compact expressions. This is a valid point you're making !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you know how to get to the relevant syntax nodes (`SimpleLambdaExpressionSyntax` and `ParenthesizedLambdaExpressionSyntax`) and just need to know how long they are.

I think you just want something like this:

```
var lineSpan = node.SyntaxTree.GetMappedLineSpan(node.Span);
var lines = lineSpan.EndLinePosition.Line - lineSpan.StartLinePosition.Line + 1;
```

There may be a more efficient or simpler way of doing it, but that should get you started.

Comment: looking at my second example in my question, this would mean by using this, the following code snippet should give me the result of 2 ? (Actually three since there's a new line without any content)

Comment: @Kavignon: No, I'd expect it to give you 6, as the lambda expression covers 6 lines. If you want to remove empty lines, and possibly remove the final line if the part of the span for that line is just whitespace followed by "}", you could do that... You'd basically need to ask the syntax tree to get each line to check it. To be honest, I don't like the idea of this "rule" anyway - and by the time you start making it more complicated by adding extra rules around which lines are counted, it feels like it's going to get harder and harder to explain to devs... I'd just rely on code review, myself.

Comment: I understand what you mean and frankly, I think I should change it to a maximum of less than 3 instructions. Is there any way to look solely for ';' in the lambda expression. I could say that if there more than 9, warning, behavior to correct?

Comment: @Kavignon: Well I wouldn't personally do even that - I'd give guidelines and then rely on code review. But if you want to count the *statements* involved, the syntax tree may well be the way forward on that front. I suggest you use the syntax tree visualizer in Visual Studio to explore that idea.

Comment: I've decided to use the visualizer and simply ignore the lines where I find WhiteSpaceTrivia or comments. Thanks for help @JonSkeet, I really appreciate it !